# Using multiple modal forms in one component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a page with many buttons, and would like each button to open its own modal form when clicked. I have a problem where using the same form/modal multiple times doesn't result in unique forms. For example, clicking the first button and then typing "asdf" into the form will also populate the form controlled by the second button.

How can I reuse my modals/forms and still keep their data distinct?

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Button, Modal, Form, Input, Radio } from 'antd';
const FormItem = Form.Item;

const CollectionCreateForm = Form.create()(
  (props) => {
    const { visible, onCancel, onCreate, form } = props;
    const { getFieldDecorator } = form;
    return (
      <Modal
        visible={visible}
        title="Create a new collection"
        okText="Create"
        onCancel={onCancel}
        onOk={onCreate}
      >
        <Form layout="vertical">
          <FormItem label="Title">
            {getFieldDecorator('title', {
              rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input the title of collection!' }],
            })(
              <Input />
            )}
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem label="Description">
            {getFieldDecorator('description')(<Input type="textarea" />)}
          </FormItem>
          <FormItem className="collection-create-form_last-form-item">
            {getFieldDecorator('modifier', {
              initialValue: 'public',
            })(
              <Radio.Group>
                <Radio value="public">Public</Radio>
                <Radio value="private">Private</Radio>
              </Radio.Group>
            )}
          </FormItem>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
);

class CollectionsPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: false,
  };
  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: true });
  }
  handleCancel = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: false });
  }
  handleCreate = () => {
    const form = this.form;
    form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (err) {
        return;
      }

      console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      form.resetFields();
      this.setState({ visible: false });
    });
  }
  saveFormRef = (form) => {
    this.form = form;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>New Collection</Button>
        <CollectionCreateForm
          ref={this.saveFormRef}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          onCreate={this.handleCreate}
        />
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>New Collection</Button>
        <CollectionCreateForm
          ref={this.saveFormRef}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          onCreate={this.handleCreate}
        />
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>New Collection</Button>
        <CollectionCreateForm
          ref={this.saveFormRef}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          onCreate={this.handleCreate}
        />
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>New Collection</Button>
        <CollectionCreateForm
          ref={this.saveFormRef}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          onCreate={this.handleCreate}
        />
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>New Collection</Button>
        <CollectionCreateForm
          ref={this.saveFormRef}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          onCreate={this.handleCreate}
        />
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>New Collection</Button>
        <CollectionCreateForm
          ref={this.saveFormRef}
          visible={this.state.visible}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel}
          onCreate={this.handleCreate}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CollectionsPage />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[interactive sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8xxmpmmpmj)

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: You can use one modal and have each item onClick trigger the modal, or you can make the item and modal into a separate component and handle the show/hide there.

Comment: Basically I have this https://codesandbox.io/s/3k0kmk8o91. I have a problem when I use the same modal multiple times in the same component.

Comment: @SrdjanRakic difficult to help without knowing more. You say you "have a problem." What problem? Do you get an error message? Is the result not what you were expecting? Describe what you expected and what you actually got. Also, the code sandbox you posted does not demonstrate the error as it doesn't "use the same modal multiple times." Please provide an example that reproduces the issue you're seeing.

Comment: @Luke M Willis The problem is that each modal references the same form, I dunno how to get a unique form/modal. I added multiple modals in the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/8xxmpmmpmj

Comment: @SrdjanRakic I understand your problem now. See my answer for both a simple fix and a better way of approaching the problem. I also edited your question to make it more clear what you're asking and include the code in the question. Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that each form is given the same props, so they are treated as the same form. In your `render` function, you create multiple `Button`s and `CollectionCreateForm`s:

```
<Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>New Collection</Button>
<CollectionCreateForm
  ref={this.saveFormRef}
  visible={this.state.visible}
  onCancel={this.handleCancel}
  onCreate={this.handleCreate}
/>
// repeated...
```

The problem with that is the fact you're passing the same props into each of these. You're only setting up a single `ref` and a single `state`. Each form is the exact same form. When one modal is visible, they're all visible.

Instead of this, you need to keep separate state and refs for each form. (**Please keep reading and don't just copy this code... this is bad code.**)

```
class CollectionsPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible1: false,
    visible2: false
  };
  showModal1 = () => {
    this.setState({ visible1: true });
  }
  showModal2 = () => {
    this.setState({ visible2: true });
  }
  handleCancel1 = () => {
    this.setState({ visible1: false });
  }
  handleCancel2 = () => {
    this.setState({ visible2: false });
  }
  handleCreate1 = () => {
    // ...
    this.setState({ visible1: false });
  }
  handleCreate2 = () => {
    // ...
    this.setState({ visible2: false });
  }
  saveFormRef1 = (form) => {
    this.form1 = form;
  }
  saveFormRef2 = (form) => {
    this.form2 = form;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>New Collection</Button>
        <CollectionCreateForm
          ref={this.saveFormRef1}
          visible={this.state.visible1}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel1}
          onCreate={this.handleCreate1}
        />
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>New Collection</Button>
        <CollectionCreateForm
          ref={this.saveFormRef2}
          visible={this.state.visible2}
          onCancel={this.handleCancel2}
          onCreate={this.handleCreate2}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I show you that to demonstrate how to fix your problem, but this is a poor way of implementing it. As you add more forms & modals, this will just spiral out of control. We can improve by delegating the logic to child components.

First, we can create a generic `ModalToggle` that encapsulates the button & form/modal in one:

```
const CollectionsPage = () => (
  <div>
    <ModalToggle 
      label="New Collection"
      modal={ CollectionFormModal }
    />
    <ModalToggle 
      label="New Collection"
      modal={ CollectionFormModal }
    />
  </div>
);
```

We can reuse the `ModalToggle` at will by moving all of the state inside so it is self sufficient:

```
class ModalToggle extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: false
  };
  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ visible: !prevState.visible }));
  }
  render() {
    const Modal = this.props.modal;
    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.toggleModal}>{this.props.label}</Button>
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.visible}
          toggleVisibility={this.toggleModal}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then, we just need to add a `CollectionFormModal` to take care of the other logic that was previously in `CollectionsPage`:

```
class CollectionFormModal extends React.Component {
  handleCancel = () => {
    this.props.toggleVisibility();
  }
  handleCreate = () => {
    // ...
    this.props.toggleVisibility();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <CollectionCreateForm
        onCancel={this.handleCancel}
        onCreate={this.handleCreate}
        visible={this.props.visible}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

You can further improve on this by moving the `Modal` parts of `CollectionCreateForm` up into `CollectionFormModal`, and instead of using `ref`s, writing your form as a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: Thanks Luke! I tried to implement your solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/kmmv6q6237, but it seems I am not doing something right. Would you mind taking a look at it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SrdjanRakic Super close. Looks like I left off one thing. You need to pass `visible` from `CollectionFormModal` into `CollectionCreateForm`. However,  I think it would be better to move the `Modal` out of `CollectionCreateForm` into `CollectionFormModal`. I updated my answer with the prop. And here's a sandbox with the `Modal` moved up: https://codesandbox.io/s/j3v1p5369w